# How to write a nested gam?

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-additive-model

I am interested in how a biological manipulation changes the behaviour of an animal species.
Here the variable $Y$ represents the measure of the behavioural trait I am interested in. I have 12 animals in each treatment level (control & manipulated). The value of $Y$ for each animal is measured multiple times at different time points. The treatment is a categorical variable $X_1$, the identity of each animal is $X_2$ and the time point is $X_3$.

[image: x-axis is time point and y-axis is Y]

As you can see from the above image, I have multiple measures per individual at each time point that belong to different animal identity and manipulation group.

I am trying to use GAM in R using the `mgcv` package to test if the biological manipulation significantly changes the value of $Y$.

I have trained a model `gam_model <- gam(Y ~ X_1 + s(X_3), data = tbl, method = 'REML')` I am not sure however, if this is the correct approach. I would think that there needs to be some nested term because $X_2$ is nested in $X_1$ because one animal can only be manipulated or non-manipulated. Is my thinking correct? What would be an appropriate formula to use?

[image]

Result of the fitted GAM looks like this which is not optimal.

Comment: It would be good to jitter your scatter plot, are the blue lines on your ggplot simply drawn by hand? It doesn't seem to align with the data at all.

Comment: From your description I do not understand why there are several measures per individual animal per time point. Did you indeed measure the same trait several time per individual at each time point ?

Comment: It also appears that your outcome variable $Y$ only spans the range $[0,1]$. Is there a special reason this is the case?

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand yes, the measurement is inherently between the range of [0,1] because this is a probability of success.

Comment: @AdamO no, that is the fit from the GAM that I drew above plotted using ggplot (not using gam.plot with the smoothing)

Comment: @CaroZ Yes, we did measure the same trait several time per individual at each time point because there can be some inherent variability in what we measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the mgcv package in R for Generalized Additive Models (GAM), it's important to account for the repeated measures within individuals and possibly also non-linear effects of time.

In your current model `gam_model <- gam(Y ~ X_1 + s(X_3), data = tbl, method = 'REML')`, you are including the treatment effect (`X_1`) and a smooth term for time (`s(X_3)`), but you're not accounting for the animal identity (`X_2`), which could lead to pseudoreplication since multiple measures for each animal are not independent observations.

A more appropriate model might include random effects for the individual animals and possibly also an interaction term between the treatment and time, to allow for different time trends in the two treatment groups. In GAMs, random effects can be included using the `s()` function with the option `bs = "re"` to specify a random effect basis. Here's how you could specify a model that includes animal identity as a random effect:

```
gam_model <- gam(Y ~ X_1 + s(X_2, bs="re") + s(X_3), data = tbl, method = 'REML')
```

If you believe that the effect of time could differ between treatment groups, you may also include an interaction term between time and treatment. Here's how you could allow for different smooths of time for each level of X_1:

```
gam_model <- gam(Y ~ X_1 + s(X_2, bs="re") + s(X_3, by=X_1), data = tbl, method = 'REML')
```

This model will fit a separate smooth function `s(X_3)` for each level of `X_1`, allowing the effect of time to differ by treatment group.

Always check the diagnostic plots and summary statistics of the model to ensure that the assumptions of the GAM are met and that the model is a good fit for your data. If the response variable Y is normally distributed, this approach should be suitable. However, if Y has a non-normal distribution (e.g., count data, binary data), you might need to use a different family of distributions appropriate for your data type.

Finally, from the plots supplied, it looks like Y is bounded by 0 and 1. In that case you might want to fit a generalised additive mixed model and specify an appropriate distribution such as beta.